DC-DC bulk converter: Build a module or buy off the shelf
I have two stepper motors onboard with two stepper drivers to control them, two endstop sensors, an esp32-c3-devkitm-1 to control the system, a smart battery powering all the system and finally, which the main focus of my question today, a DC-DC buck converter to convert the around 12V from the battery to a solid 5V to feed it to the esp32 based board.
Now I am looking into bettering this solution and I am looking into either buying a more reliable module that is ready to use and wire it to my PCB like the old converter I used or use an IC and build my own with some external componenets and this will be added to same PCB, I will include a screenshot for the current PCB too.
I looked into this for some time and I feel a little bit confused, is there another approach then the two approaches I mentioned earlier ? I mean are there converter modules that require a few componenets to build rather than purchasing the IC and building everything from scratch ? An example to the modules that I am referring to is:
https://www.arrow.com/en/products/mgs104805/cosel
I am aiming for 3A max output current from the converter to stay safe, I generally need less. The product we are designing is currently an internal project with a the possibility to commercialize it.
https://www.roboter-bausatz.de/media/pdf/85/05/e6/RBS12876-Motor-Datenblatt.pdf https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMC2209_datasheet_rev1.09.pdf https://www.roboter-bausatz.de/p/mks-tmc2209-schrittmotortreiber?sPartner=8&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwpbi4BhByEiwAMC8JnRh8Mw2v2SjbjNeQ8kWJWzkorMDzzsv1W0KWsemaP086DnnEUlzf7xoCU7cQAvD_BwE https://www.feyelektronik.de/downloads/db-pa-lep1014.pdf
and finally the bulk dc dc converter that I am currently using and planning on replacing it with a more reliable converter.
https://protosupplies.com/product/lm2596s-adjustable-dc-dc-step-down-sy-dc3003-module/


You should use enlarged tracks for the "step" motors ... and the power supply pins also.

What is your present converter not doing for you, that you need?

@Antonio51 Thank you for your comment, surely I will in my next version of the PCB, I am a beginner also in designing PCBs, this project is actually my master thesis so I am doing everything.

@Aaron thank you for your comment, I am just looking for a more reliable converter as I have been told that the type of converter that I used is not reliable in long life devices (the device should survive around 10 years) that is why I am looking for alternatives, now I have two approaches, either look for a ready to use module and just plug it into the sytem, or an IC module that only need a few external componenets.

Also the system wll be placed in an environment with relatively high power, it will be placed inside an x-ray machine with current going until 350 µA and voltage of around 225 kV, also not sure how would this contribute to my decision making process.

I would make sure it's in a very good faraday shield.

I am currently checking this type of converter modules that require very few external components like the THN 15-1211 from TRACO Power, it has almost no external components required and some external components needed for EMI protection
https://www.tracopower.com/sites/default/files/products/application_notes/thn15_emc_consideration.pdf?t=1729036801

My initial inquiry was to check which approach is better, picking one of the modules like the THN 15-1211 or buy the ones that are ready to use like the SY-DC3003 found in the link below (altough I was not able to find reliable dc dc modules like the SY-DC3003 which is supposedly not reliable)
https://protosupplies.com/product/lm2596s-adjustable-dc-dc-step-down-sy-dc3003-module/

I'm not 100% sure exactly what you're looking for, but if I understand your question correctly I think Pololu might have what you need. Out of the box step-down converters with a variety of voltage and current output options. Can easily solder on to your PCB with a few header pins or mount separately and use wires.I'm not entirely sure why the module you're currently using or a component like the one you linked, but with higher output current, wouldn't work for you so maybe some more information would be helpful.

thank you for your answer. My input voltage from the smart battery is around 12V and what I need from the converter is a solid 5V with around 3A max current to feed it to the esp32 based motherboard. I am researching the best approach to be able to make the decision, this is part of my master thesis so I am interested in the reasons also for documentation that is why I am asking which approach is the best but selecting the converter later on should be pretty straightforward. I hope this clarifies my inquiry.
